# Most peformant set structure in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, set

I want to have a list of strings that is unique and so everytime I get a new string that I should push onto the list I need to check if the list contains the item before pushing it on the list. This seems unperformant.

However, if I use a hash structure and store the items as keys, is there some way to make this more performant than a simple array?

I guess I am simply wondering what the most performant set data structure exists in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a Set will be much faster than checking for an existing value (O(1) for set vs. O(n) for an array).

```
var s = Set();

s.add(1); // s is (1)
s.add(2);
s.add(3);
s.add(1)
s.add(1)

// s is now (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers (Chrome 38+, IE11+) the `Set` type is defined, it is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Otherwise, in JavaScript, `Object` values (a fundamental type in ECMAScript) are internally implemented as hashtables - so the fastest conceptual "`HashSet`" structure would exist as a generalisation of of a hashtable with a disregarded value-type.

Here's how I'd do it (if `Set` was unavailable):

```
function StringSet() {
    this.values = {};
    this.add = function(value) {
        value = value.toUpperCase(); // use UpperCase for string normalization because of how casing rules work in different languages, especially Turkish
        this.values[ value ] = true; // use bool values as stubs
    };
    this.contains = function(value) {
        value = value.toUpperCase();
        return value in this.values; // JavaScript has a fast `in` operator which runs in `O(1)` time
    }
}

var foo = new StringSet();
foo.add("bar");
assert( foo.contains("bar") );
```

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that your StringSet is case-insensitive, whereas a native Set is case-sensitive. The case-insensitive matching could certainly be useful - just wanted to highlight the difference.